# Configure distance of zoom axis

Tags: python, zooming

I am trying to zoom-in my plot, however, I am getting two different undesired plots. The following figure exemplifies what I am getting.

[image]
[image]

This is my code, I am not sure what the problem might be because I don't have such an experience with this **zoomed_inset_axes**. Any guidance will be much appreciated.

```
def doscatterplot2(xcoord,ycoord,labellist,limits,ax=None):
   ax = ax
   ax.scatter(xcoord, ycoord,label=labellist,marker='o',facecolors='none', edgecolors='seagreen')
   # Zoom 1.
   axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, -1,loc='center',bbox_to_anchor=(0.1, 0.1),bbox_transform=ax.figure.transFigure)
   axins.scatter(xcoord, ycoord)
   axins.axis([-0.1, 0.1, -25, 35])
   axins.xaxis.tick_top()
   mark_inset(ax, axins, loc1=2, loc2=4)
   axins.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=1, prune='lower'))
return
```

Comment: Hi, can you please provide an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run the code and be able to modify it?

Comment: Sorry, I have just fixed. Basically, the bbox_to_anchor, runs from 0 to 1 and I was setting it on a specific position. Thank you anyway!

Comment: No worries, good for you!